# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Variable' "ERROR"

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, anaconda

I have used tensor-flow for ONE day, but there come some troubles, when I import tensor-flow, there would be AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'variable'

I use Windows10, Python 3.5.3, Anaconda-3 4.4.0

here is my test code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
my_var = tf.Variable(tf.linspace(10.0, 13.0, 4)) 
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print (sess.run(my_var))
```

I got this error:
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have written a module, `random.py`, which shadows the standard library's [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module. Try renaming the file and check if the error goes away. You can tell it's importing your random.py at the bottom of the stacktrace you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Replace 'variable' with 'Variable', for example following code gives error:

```
initial_value=tf.random.normal(shape=(2,2))
a = tf.variable(initial_value)
print(a)
```

but this code gives successful output

```
initial_value=tf.random.normal(shape=(2,2))
a = tf.Variable(initial_value)
print(a)
```