# Installing Tensorflow for Python 3.6 (Windows 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

It could be a replicate question, but none of the existing questiones have been useful for me. I've tried all the solutions given here ([stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip))
I get this error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for tensorflow

I have this version of the pip on my Pycharm machine with Python 3.6 (Windows 10):

> Package    Version ------- 
>   pip        18.0 --
>   setuptools 40.4.3 -- 
>   wheel      0.32.0

I would like to install *tensorflow* and I have tried to take a look at this [link](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow) as most of the people suggested.
Does anybody want to guide me in my installation?

Comment: are you installing the cpu or gpu version?

Answer (score 0):

below command worked for me.
pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl

Answer (score -1):

#### Installation Commands

The following commands are based on the following installation guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip).

#### using cmd

```
C:> pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow // cpu
C:> pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu // gpu
```

#### using Anaconda

```
C:> conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5 
C:> activate tensorflow
(tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
(tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

You can get step by step instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows)

Comment: It doesn't work. It give me the error  "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command." But the pip is not 9, but already 18!

Comment: @StefanoVacca Can you try `python -m pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl` or `pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl`

Comment: It seems installed, but it doesn't recognize Variable as command. It gets this error: "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Variable'".

Comment: Anyway, the link that you gave to me in the comment doesn't work for Windows. Only mac!

Comment: Oh sorry! This is the correct link `https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.11.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: For the error `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Variable` my guess is it has something to do with the code, please post your code snippet with the error. Not in the comments, may be a new question if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317706/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-variable-error) doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: The 'https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.11.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl' is not supported for my platform. It shows the error 'tensorflow-1.11.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform'.